# What is SQL statement to Delete Current Record?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a delete button on my microsoft access form.

In the OnClick for the button I have VBA code and in that VBA code I can identify the current record using Me.CurrentRecord.

What is the SQL statement do delete that specific record?

```
DELETE FROM tablename where ???
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no concept of "current record" in SQL. You need to get the PK of the current record and use that with the `DELETE` statement. **Don't forget to use parameters**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the form delete the record:

```vb
' DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDelete
' DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: I'm new (obviously) ... Thanks Gustav